# how can I make the background as long as the page?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, opencart

I've encountered a problem with a website I'm changing. The background of the page does not continue like the banners I've put on the sides and the site looks horrible because of this. Could you please help me figure out how to prolong the background of the container as long as the banners( 1500px)? 
I'm sorry my description of the problem is so vague, I am putting a link here to the website with the problem so you can better see what I mean.
It is http://gentlecare.ro/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=6

Thanks a lot,
Iris

Comment: I've managed to make the background longer, thanks to all your responses, but the footer always ends up with no flowers on the side, no matter how long I make those banners and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

You can use background-size property. Limited to modern browsers thought. You can also just strech the background image.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

to the end of your `container-inner` div to stretch the container to it's content

Or better use [CSS Clearfix Best Cross browser solution](http://umairj.com/68/css-clearfix-best-cross-browser-solution/)

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you have a CSS syntax error:

```
    #column_left {
     float:left;
      width:230px;
      clear:; // needs to be "clear:both"
      padding:30px 0 0 10px;
                 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the banners have a fixed height, you could add the same height attribute to your #container id.

```
#container {
width: 990px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: left;
background: url(../image/layout/bg-container.jpg) center 0 repeat-y;
height: 1504px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="container-inner">
<div id="header">
<div id="column_left">
<div id="column_right"> </div>
<div id="content">
<div style="clear:both"></div>// add this
<div id="footer">
<div style="clear:both"></div>// add this
</div>
```

and this

```
 #container {
        background-image: url("../image/layout/bg-container.jpg");
        background-size: 990px 1518px;
    }

#footer {
    background: url("../image/layout/bg-footer.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    margin: -130px 0 0;
    padding: 70px 20px 0;
    position: relative;
}
```